# Infinite square well problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

A one-dimensional box contains a particle whose ground state energy is $\epsilon$. It is observed that a small disturbance causes the particle to emit a photon of
energy $h \nu = 8 \epsilon$, after which it is stable. Just before emission, a possible state of the particle in terms of the energy eigenstates {$\psi_1, \psi_2...$} would be,

Ans is $\frac{\psi_2+2\psi_3}{\sqrt{5}}.$

My take:
    Since $E_n= n^2 \epsilon$ (For 1D box: $E_n= n^2 E_1, n=1,2,3..$). It says that after the emission of $8 \epsilon$, it comes to a stable state, which means it comes to one of the eigenstates. If $E$ is the energy just before the emisson, then,

$E-8 \epsilon= n^2 \epsilon \Rightarrow E=8 \epsilon+ n^2 \epsilon =  9\epsilon, 12 \epsilon....$ (Given state (answer)'s energy must be one of them.)

But Given state corresponds to the energy: $E_2 \frac{1}{5}+E_3$$\frac{4}{5}=8 \epsilon.$

Which does not match with my approach, Please help.

Comment: @Joh Rennie,  So you think it is off topic ?. The policy of this stack exchange is that OP should show some efforts towards the problem. Didn't he show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy of a superposition state is also a superposition, not a weighted average. The state in your answer is a superposition of $E_2 = 4\epsilon$ and $E_3 = 9\epsilon$. This means that, upon decay to the stable state $\psi_1$, it could have emitted a photon of energy $8\epsilon$ if it decayed from state $\psi_3$ (probability $4/5$), or a photon of energy $3\epsilon$ if it decayed from state $\psi_2$ (probability $1/5$). What you calculated was the expectation value of the energy, which need not be equal to any energy eigenstate.

The way to approach the original question is to find two energy levels such that $E_m - E_n = 8\epsilon$. Since $E_n = n^2\epsilon$, the equation reduces to $m^2 - n^2 = 8$. You need to find two square numbers whose difference is 8. The only answer is $m = 3$ and $n = 1$. You should prove this as part of your answer.

As long as the wavefunction has some component in the state corresponding to $\psi_3$, then it has a non-zero probability of emitting an $8\epsilon$ photon by decaying to state $\psi_1$. So, any wavefunction given by
$$\sum_n c_n\psi_n$$
will be a possible answer as long as $c_3 \neq 0$.

Comment: Can you give any source for the statement that the energy of a superposition state is also a superposition. As far as my understanding goes, the particle in this case can only produce a photon of 4e or 9e with the relative probability of doing so in the ratio of 1:4.

Comment: @RishabhJain What you said is exactly what "superposition" means. Here's a source: http://physics.gmu.edu/~dmaria/590%20Web%20Page/public_html/qm_topics/superposition/superposition.html

Comment: The page shows the calculation of the expected energy value. However, you cannot equation this with the actual energy in my opinion. The photon that comes out from a small disturbance can only be one of the values which correspond with the difference in energy bands. Else, the spectrum of Hydrogen would not consist of discrete lines!!

Comment: @RishabhJain We are saying the same thing. I said the question-asker was wrong because the expectation value was used. The correct method is to use either of the allowed eigenvalue energies to get the correct energy transition. The first paragraph of my answer agrees with your comments.